# Not changing background color in JS

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let colorOptArr = [
  document.getElementsByClassName("bx1"),
  document.getElementsByClassName("bx2"),
  document.getElementsByClassName("bx3"),
  document.getElementsByClassName("bx4")
];

for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  colorOptArr[i].style.backgroundColor = `red`;
}
```

```html
<section class="opt">
  <div class="colors bx1"></div>
  <div class="colors bx2"></div>
  <div class="colors bx3"></div>
  <div class="colors bx4"></div>
</section>
```

Why this code is not changing the color of the div and giving the error that can't change background of **undefined** value

Comment: `getElementS` is plural, it returns a *list* of elements. You have an array of arrays. Each of `colorOptArr[i]` is an array, not a single element.

Comment: Also, arrays are zero indexed; by starting `i` at `1`, you're skipping the first element.

Comment: @deceze An array of [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) instances (which are array-like, but not arrays). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Let's not confuse the poor chap more than necessary. ;)

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName() returns an HTMLCollection, that is, it behaves like an array.

    let colorOptArr = [
      document.getElementsByClassName("bx1"),
      document.getElementsByClassName("bx2"),
      document.getElementsByClassName("bx3"),
      document.getElementsByClassName("bx4")
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < colorOptArr.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < colorOptArr[i].length; j++) {
        colorOptArr[i][j].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
    }

Comment: try `let colorOptArr = document.querySelectorAll(".colors");`

Comment: so how can I do it?

Comment: from this code I want to give different color to every div

Comment: ```
let colorOptArr = [
  document.querySelectorAll(".bx1"),
  document.querySelectorAll(".bx2"),
  document.querySelectorAll(".bx3"),
  document.querySelectorAll(".bx4")
];

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  colorOptArr[i].forEach(element => element.style["background-color"] = `red`);
}
```

Comment: @DineshChandraPandey - The [linked question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return) tell you how to fix it. That's the point of closing a question as a duplicate.